# How to debug problems with the javafx native bundle for Windows?

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine, dukescript

I'm trying to package a JavaFX/DukeScript application into native bundles.
For Windows that's achieved with Inno Setup, that's what the javafxpackager uses.
I can't find much documentation about it, so I'll create a question and provide the answers I find below.

Related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073292/netbeans-java-javafx-native-packaging-with-additional-files-and-folders), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311598/java-how-to-create-a-working-exe-from-a-native-installer), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136770/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-execed-program-in-inno-setup), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441938/how-does-output-redirection-work-in-inno-setup)

Answer (score 4):

So I've created a build.xml Ant script using e(fx)clipse (see example [here](https://github.com/goGPS-Project/goGPS_FX/blob/master/buildwin/build.xml)).
I've been following [this excellent blog post](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/).
Now, the bundle task worked and produced an installer and executable app.
I've been having trouble running the app and couldn't see a stack trace.
So here's how to display a window with the stack trace when running the executable from the command line:

```
 goGPS_FX.exe /Debug
```

That brings up a popup, with the stack trace. In my case, a jar dependency was missing. So just for testing, I manually added that jar under `deploy\bundles\goGPS_FX\app\libs`.

For the JavaFX launcher to include this new jar, I need to modify the file `app\package.cfg`.
As far as I understand, that's JavaFX specific, it's not needed by Inno Setup.
Also, I couldn't find much information about this file.
Anyway, there's a property called `app.classpath` we can update.
The other relevant property is `app.mainclass`. Here the mainclass is not specified with the standard dotted notation, but rather as a path:

```
app.mainclass=org/gogpsproject/GoGPS_Fx
```

Finally, other properties might be available. One I've found was:

```
jvmarg.1=-Djavafx.verbose=true
```

So that's a way to pass arguments to the jvm, should you need to.